# Cannot create commands from unopened database

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, dependency-injection, xamarin.forms

I've searched around quite a lot and I cannot find any answers to this.

I am writing a Xamarin Forms Mobile application, it seems when I minimise the application and then reopen it or one of my activities get launched the following exception gets thrown:

```
SQLiteConnection.CreateCommand (System.String cmdText, System.Object[] ps)
SQLite.SQLiteException: Cannot create commands from unopened database
SQLiteConnection.CreateCommand (System.String cmdText, System.Object[] ps)
TableQuery`1[T].GenerateCommand (System.String selectionList)
TableQuery`1[T].GetEnumerator ()
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T]..ctor (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] collection) [0x00062] in :0
Enumerable.ToList[TSource] (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] source)
AsyncTableQuery`1[T].<ToListAsync>b__9_0 ()
Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke ()
Task.Execute ()
```

Here is my code:

**Generic Repository** (Where the Sqlite instance gets created)

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : Entity, new()
{
     private readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection _db;

    public Repository(string dbPath)
    {
        _db = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
        _db.CreateTableAsync<T>().Wait();
    }
}
```

**The IOC registration**

```
FreshIOC.Container.Register<IRepository<Settings>>(new Repository<Settings>(dbPath)); // FreshIOC is a wrapper around TinyIOC
```

**In my App.xaml.cs OnResume**

```
protected override void OnResume()
{
    SQLiteAsyncConnection.ResetPool();
}
```

The above with `ResetPool` I put that in to see if it would make a difference but it did not.

**URL Activity**

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    var url = Intent.Data.ToString();
    var split = url.Split(new[] { "ombi://", "_" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    if (split.Length > 1)
    {
        var dbLocation = new FileHelper().GetLocalFilePath("ombi.db3");
        var repo = new Repository<OmbiMobile.Models.Entities.Settings>(dbLocation);
        var settings = repo.Get().Result;
        foreach (var s in settings)
        {
            var i = repo.Delete(s).Result;
        }
        repo.Save(new Settings
        {
            AccessToken = split[1],
            OmbiUrl = split[0]
        });
    }

    Intent startup = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
    StartActivity(startup);
    Finish();
}
```

I am not sure what else to do or look for, I can't seem to find any information about this sort of error.

**Update:**

After more debugging it seems to only happen after the Url activity has finished.
I have removed the DB code from the Activity and it still seems to happen. Once the Activity has launched the main `App()` then runs this code:

```
var repo = FreshIOC.Container.Resolve<IRepository<Settings>>();
try
{
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        settings = (await repo.Get()).FirstOrDefault();
    }).Wait();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
    throw;
}
```

This where the error is happening. It happens when the `Get()` is called which calls `return _db.Table<T>().ToListAsync();`

I have tried making everything async (didn't help), making the repository, connection and where we do `CreateTableAsync` async and still no luck.

Comment: May i know which version of Sqlite you're using, let me check whether it has known bugs of this sort since you're not doing anything wrong here.

Comment: @DharaniKumar `sqlite-net-pcl` package is version `1.4.118`

Comment: I took a look at the API, the error was thrown if your connection wasn't open inside create command and the only way a live connection is closed is when Dispose is called. 

Is it possible to post the StacK Trace please, Let's see if can get anything inside that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for @Nkosi to his insight and advice, that was much appreciated but none of the solutions worked.

After pulling down the sqlite.net-pcl library (saved by OSS again!) and debugging through it, it seemed that every time my `Activity` launched there is a check to see if the connection was [open](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/blob/5603ee0c66276e2242f4bd5bf654afb9bfc91db9/src/SQLite.cs#L809) and it wasn't, the only place it was being set to open is when the `SqliteConnection` was [constructed](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/blob/5603ee0c66276e2242f4bd5bf654afb9bfc91db9/src/SQLite.cs#L282). Now the way I wrote it, it was a singleton but stupidly my `Repository<T>` implemented `IDisposable`. So my IOC container was disposing of the `SqliteConnection` but it was never recreating it due to it being a singleton.

TL;DR removed `IDisposable` implementation on the repository because the `SqliteConnection` was a singleton.

Answer (score 8):

You are making synchronous blocking calls like `.Wait()` and `.Result` that could potentially cause deadlocks when mixed with an asynchronous API.

`SQLiteAsyncConnection` was meant to be used asynchronously.

One common work around is to create event handlers that would allow for async non blocking calls to be made.

For example when calling `CreateTableAsync` in the repository

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : Entity, new() {
     private readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection _db;

    public Repository(string dbPath) {
        _db = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
        createTable += onCreateTable; //Subscribe to event
        createTable(this, EventArgs.Empty); //Raise event
    }

    private event EventHandler createTable = delegate { };
    private async void onCreateTable(object sender, EventArgs args) {
        createTable -= onCreateTable; //Unsubscribe from event
        await _db.CreateTableAsync<T>(); //async non blocking call
    }

    //...
}
```

The repository abstraction appears to have an asynchronous API yet there are synchronous calls.

Again this can cause deadlock and is not advised.

The code needs to be refactored to be async all the way through if the intent is to have a responsive UI or use  *SQLite.Net*, the non-async version, to make synchronous calls.

Refactoring of the URL Activity to be asynchronous would look like this following the same format as above.

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    creating += onCreateCore; //subscribe to event
    creating(this, EventArgs.Empty); //raise event
}

private event EventHandler creating = delegate { };
private async void onCreateCore(object sender, EventArgs args) {
    creating -= onCreateCore; //unsubscribe to event
    var url = Intent.Data.ToString();
    var split = url.Split(new[] { "ombi://", "_" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    if (split.Length > 1) {
        var dbLocation = new FileHelper().GetLocalFilePath("ombi.db3");
        var repo = new Repository<OmbiMobile.Models.Entities.Settings>(dbLocation);
        var settings = await repo.Get();
        foreach (var s in settings) {
            var i = await repo.Delete(s);
        }
        repo.Save(new Settings {
            AccessToken = split[1],
            OmbiUrl = split[0]
        });
    }

    Intent startup = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
    StartActivity(startup);
    Finish();
}
```

### UPDATE

Also from a design perspective, the initialization of the connection should be inverted out of the repository and managed externally (SRP).

```
public interface ISQLiteAsyncProvider {
    SQLiteAsyncConnection GetConnection();
}

public class DefaultSQLiteAsyncProvider : ISQLiteAsyncProvider {
    private readonly Lazy<SQLiteAsyncConnection> connection;

    public DefaultSQLiteAsyncProvider(string path) {
        connection = new Lazy<SQLiteAsyncConnection>(() => new SQLiteAsyncConnection(path));
    }

    public SQLiteAsyncConnection GetConnection() {
        return connection.Value;
    }
}
```

Playing with the idea of an asynchronous lazy initialization for the connection using

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides support for asynchronous lazy initialization.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
public class LazyAsync<T> : Lazy<Task<T>> {
    /// <summary>
    ///  Initializes a new instance of the LazyAsync`1 class. When lazy initialization
    ///  occurs, the specified initialization function is used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="valueFactory">The delegate that is invoked to produce the lazily initialized Task when it is needed.</param>
    public LazyAsync(Func<Task<T>> valueFactory) :
        base(() => Task.Run(valueFactory)) { }
}
```

This makes it possible now to refactor the repository to use lazy initialization, which allowed for the removal of the event handler in the repository

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : Entity, new() {

    public Repository(ISQLiteAsyncProvider provider) {
        this.connection = new LazyAsync<SQLiteAsyncConnection>(await () => {
            var db = provider.GetConnection();
            await db.CreateTableAsync<T>();
            return db;
        });
    }

    private readonly LazyAsync<SQLiteAsyncConnection> connection;

    public async Task<List<T>> Get() {
        var _db = await connection.Value;
        return await _db.Table<T>().ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<T> Get(int id) {
        var _db = await connection.Value;
        return await _db.Table<T>().Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }

    public async Task<int> Save(T entity) {
        var _db = await connection.Value;
        return entity.Id == 0 
            ? await _db.InsertAsync(entity) 
            : await_db.UpdateAsync(entity);
    }

    public async Task<int> Delete(T entity) {
        var _db = await connection.Value;
        return await _db.DeleteAsync(entity);
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) {
        if (disposing) {
            // get rid of managed resources
        }
        // get rid of unmanaged resources
    }
}
```

And registered like

```
// same instance should be used for other repositories
var provider = new DefaultSQLiteAsyncProvider(dbPath); 
var settingsRepository = new Repository<Settings>(provider);
FreshIOC.Container.Register<IRepository<Settings>>(settingsRepository);
```

Comment: I have updated the OP with my finidings, +1 since this is a good idea anyway.

Comment: @JamieRees can you show the repository in its entirety. I have a suspicion about the design and the creation of the connection. Might need to do some more refactoring with the use of the connection. I am thinking of abstracting that out as well.

Comment: Update OP with the repository

Comment: @JamieRees I did some further refactoring.

Comment: Didn't seem to work, I've updated my OP again with further info I have found

Comment: @JamieRees Ok that new update shows that it is still async/threading related. Can you show what encapsulates the code you showed in the update? Something is running in a separate thread before the connection has time to do its thing.

Comment: I've found the issue, please see my answer, thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Curious though. That last refactor  I had given where I left the repository disposable but was not explicitly disposing of the connection within because of the singleton. That was still failing? I had removed the connection for the same reason. It does make a lot of sense that disposal being the culprit. Happy coding and all the best on the project.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error, but was not due to `Disposable` implementation. For some unknown reason it broke if I had the following:

```
lock (locker)
{
    foreach (var item in database.Table<DBItems>()) //It broke on this line
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

So I changed the line to

```
foreach (var item in database.Table<DBItems>().ToList()) //Notice the "ToList()"
```

Problem solved...